# How to use OpenCV with Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

When I attempt to deploy my application to Heroku I receive the following error:

> ````
> File "/app/project/app/_ _init__.py", line 22, in <module>
> File "/app/project/app/views.py", line 6, in <module>
> import cv2
> from .cv2 import *
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/_ _init__.py", line 4, in <module>
> 2018-03-24T20:40:55.986945+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory```
> ````

OpenCV is unable to find the libsm directory, however this application runs correctly locally. I have tried using a specific buildpack however those did not seem to find my `site-packages` folder.

How do I use openCV (python) on Heroku?

Answer (score 39):

You can install these missing libraries taking advantage of the [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt).

At the time of this writing, I have succesfully done it [for this repo](https://github.com/jeromevonk/flask_face_detection), with the following steps:

1. Add heroku-buildpack-apt to your buildpacks on Heroku platform
2. Create a file named Aptfile and add the following libs:

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

(one per line). Example [here](https://github.com/jeromevonk/flask_face_detection/blob/master/Aptfile).

**Edit**: in newer versions of OpenCV, you need only to list `python-opencv` on the Aptfile, as seen in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html).

Comment: It worked for me, many thanks! But I would like to know what I've actually done... I don't have any experience with these build packs.

Comment: @mimic, [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)  can be seen as a "set of scripts, and depending on the programming language, the scripts will retrieve dependencies, output generated assets or compiled code, and more". In my app, I wanted to use Python3, so I added the Python buildpack on Heroku. As some needed libraries were still missing from the system, the heroku-buildpack-apt let's you manage packages in a way similar 
 to how [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)) works.

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks a lot! This should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 11):

Use opencv-python-headless as it is out of libSM6 dependency.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580480/12597089) out.
Add the following line your requirements.txt and remove the old open-cv entry:

```
opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.32
```

Comment: perfect! I was trying many things, at last this worked for me, Thank you:)

Answer (score 6):

New Aptfile and requirements.txt attributes works for me:

#### in Aptfile

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

#### in requirements.txt

```
opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.32
```

---

Remember to have the Buildpack included in settings.

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install some dependencies, as Heroku will not automatically do it for you.

1. Add an ***Aptfile*** in your project directory and add the below file

- libsm6
- libxrender1
- libfontconfig1
- libice6

  NOTE: Aptfile should not have any .txt or any other extension. Just like the
  Procfile

2. Push the edited code to Github
3. In heroku dashboard, 
   goto your-app --> settings --> buildpacks --> add buildpacks --> *https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git* 
   copy and paste this link --> add buildpack
4. Deploy your app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, be sure to use unix style line endings in the Aptfile when following @Lelo suggestion above

Comment: @Bawantha please find an explanation here: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html#:~:text=Text%20files%20created%20on%20DOS,(%22%5Cn%22).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Lelo's answer regarding the installation of libraries, OpenCV has changed their required libraries (4.4.0 at the time of writing).

Hence, to get the latest ones, you just need `python-opencv` in the Aptfile instead of the other libraries.

This was referred to [Install OpenCV-Python in Ubuntu](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html).

Comment: For me, `python3-opencv` (note the added 3) worked, and without it Heroku reported that the package was not found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having error like `ImportError: libSM.so.6` , in this case one needs to add libsm1 (all in lower case) to aptfile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is related to a missing shared library `libGL.so.1` that is required by the OpenCV library (`cv2`) used in your code. This issue is commonly seen when running applications in headless environments like Heroku, which doesn't have the necessary graphical libraries installed.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Update your `Aptfile` to include the `libgl1-mesa-dev` package, which provides the `libGL.so.1` library:

   ```
   tesseract-ocr
   tesseract-ocr-eng
   libsm6
   libxrender1
   libfontconfig1
   libice6
   libglu1
   libgl1-mesa-dev
   ```
2. Commit and push the changes to your repository.
3. Trigger a new deployment on Heroku. The updated `Aptfile` will prompt Heroku to install the additional dependencies specified.

By adding `libgl1-mesa-dev`, you should be able to resolve the missing `libGL.so.1` error and successfully execute your code on Heroku.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead .it worked for me.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```