# Heroku : Unable to locate package libsm6

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a flask app which uses openCV on heroku from my [github respository](https://github.com/Psychac/backendPuzzleMaster) .
I included the [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git) buildpack with python buildpack and I even tried the method given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004957/11784170). On which I am getting the following error. Someone please help me to get this running.

```
-----> Using buildpacks:

       1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

       2. heroku/python

-----> Apt app detected

-----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache

-----> Updating apt caches

       Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]

       Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease [86.7 kB]

       Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]

       Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]

       Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1,275 kB]

       Get:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [335 kB]

       Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]

       Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [925 kB]

       Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [778 kB]

       Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,050 kB]

       Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,362 kB]

       Fetched 17.6 MB in 2s (7,275 kB/s)

       Reading package lists...

-----> Fetching .debs for libsm6

       Reading package lists...

       Building dependency tree...

E: Unable to locate package libsm6

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Apt app.

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: if you're still having this issue, perhaps add some debugging details. and consider asking on another stackexchange, perhaps one closer to linux (this complains about packaging) or specific to server administration (https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I managed to fix it back then itself. Turns out the issue was with the line endings of the proc file, they were set to windows line endings and not linux ones, changing them to linux ones did the trick @ChristophRackwitz