# Errors deploy Flask app to Heroku due to OpenCV

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have been trying to deploy my Flask app in Heroku, but when running `heroku open`, it seems fail to start the server.

This is the message from `heroku logs --tail`
https://pastebin.com/F282iigp

Here is my `requirements.txt`

```
Flask
Jinja2
Werkzeug
opencv-python
pillow
Plim
flask_mako
futures
flask-cors==3.0.8
scikit-image==0.14.0
numpy==1.15.2
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.5.0+cpu
torchvision==0.6.0+cpu
```

I have also tried to execute this in command line

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
```

and include an `Aptfile`:

```
libsm6
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596267/cant-make-opencv-work-on-heroku

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use OpenCV with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469764/how-to-use-opencv-with-heroku)

Comment: @Ehsan I actually followed both of your threads

Answer (score 0):

try to add  this in requirement :

opencv==3.1